# Arangodb not connecting using localhost but accessible using external IP

Tags: arangodb, pyarango

I installed `arangodb` on single node ubuntu server, followed [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-arangodb-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

below is my `arangod.conf` file:

```
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529
endpoint = tcp://<internalserverIP>:8529
```

I did enable both of them.

Now i am able to access arango using below on my local system

```
curl --dump - http://<externalserverIP>:8529/_api/version
```

so far so good.

now when i try to access same on installed ubuntu server using:

```
curl --dump - http://127.0.0.1:8529/_api/version
```

i am getting below error:

> Access to the page:
>   ... has been denied for the following reason:
>
> Blocked by Content Checking.
>
> Categories:
>
> Proxies

what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by resetting the proxy to its default by using the below command.

```
export http_proxy=
```